# Hapi route conflict with static route

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

For some reason my static route make conflict with the other route.

**Static content route:**

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{p*}',
    handler: {
        directory: {
            path: '.',
            redirectToSlash: true,
            listing: false
        }
    }
});
```

**Second route**

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{p1}/{p2}',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        //...
    }
});
```

**In my index file I load the static content:**

```
...    
<link href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
```

In this case bootstrap.min.css is loaded, but style.css not. All files inside first level folders didn't work. If I move style.css in `/styles/test/style.css` its work...

**Update:**

Actually static route is ignored and static requests are redirected to the other route. Any idea how to fix this without changing the route?

Comment: The /styles/style.css path matches the `/{p1}/{p2}` path and is more specific than your catch-all route so that handler will be invoked. That's just how the router works in hapi. I suggest keeping static files under a named subpath e.g. `/assets/{p*}` etc

Comment: Thanks @MattHarrison it works. I still don't know why in hapi documentation they didn't suggest something like that.

Comment: There are times when a real catch-all is useful too (custom 404 pages etc).